# Do you have any suggestions for further improving my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424749/why-is-the-relative-path-of-my-file-not-being-recognized-by-my-application) was migrated from Super User to Stack Overflow. I don't know why I have been voted down for my question. I feel that my question is fairly thorough. I have asked for the reason for the down-vote but I haven't received any explanations. As a result, I have posted this question here for possible explanations.

Please point out what is lacking in my question and how I can further improve it.

Comment: Patience, maybe...?  It was only downvoted once and I'm not seeing any *glaring* flaws with your question. *Potentially*, a more complete MCVE would help...but I'm not seeing anything here that'd make me want to downvote it.

Comment: For starters you need to tag the question properly with the language and technologies that you're using.  As it is none of the people using those relevant languages/technologies are going to find your question, as neither of your existing tags are actually directing you to your target audience.

Comment: Add the tag for C as well.

Comment: @Servy My question is merely about using absolute and relative paths. It has no connection with any language. Hence, I posted this question first on SuperUser.

Comment: @a_sid So the code that you've shown is entirely irrelevant, and has nothing to do with your question?  Then why is it there, and how is this a programming question if the code is irrelevant?

Comment: @Servy The code I have posted is general C code for opening and reading a file. I figured posting the code would make my question more thorough. This is why I posted the question on SuperUser first because I wasn't seeking programming help with this question.

Comment: @a_sid Of your question is asking about the behavior of some particular C code, when faced with various inputs, then it's a C question, and should be tagged accordingly.  If your question *isn't* about the behavior of that C code, then I don't understand what it's actually asking.

Comment: @Servy I have added the tag for C. My actual purpose for asking this question was to find out why specifying the relative paths did not work for me. I added the code to give more context to the question.

Comment: @a_sid So, like I said, you're asking about the behavior of some particular C code and wondering why it acts differently when faced with different inputs.  That makes it a C question, because you're asking about the behavior of some C code.  Without the code the question is meaningless and unanswerable, and one would need to understand how the given C code works in order to answer the question, meaning you want experienced C coders looking at your question, which means you want the C tag.

Comment: @Servy Okay. I now understand your point.